# Error in plotly: unused argument (base_url = "https://plot.ly")

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm following the tutorial on R-Shiny/plotly dashboard - http://moderndata.plot.ly/dashboards-in-r-with-shiny-plotly/

And getting this error after runApp():

> ```
> Error in plotly(username = "Viola.Rudenko", key = "%%", base_url = "https://plot.ly") : 
>   unused argument (base_url = "https://plot.ly")
> ```

I followed the instructions on setting up my account here - https://plot.ly/r/getting-started/

When I run  plotly:::verify("Viola.Rudenko")

I get:

> [1] "" Warning message: Couldn't find Viola.Rudenko

I get the same error for my API key. But I did sign up a month ago and do have plotly account! What am I missing here?

Cheers,
Viola

Comment: Their library has changed, it seems that plotly function doesn't have base_url argument anymore. It's signature now is
`function (username, key)`, so tutorial probably was not updated to reflect that. Try dropping base_url argument

Comment: Thanks a lot Roman! It did work :) Surprisingly, when I dropped it yesterday it did not work - but since then I installed additional packages/restarted my laptop. Should have checked on it again.